# How to detect git on VSCode without administrator right?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When I try to start Visual Studio Code without administrator right, I get VSCode report like "It look like git is not installed on your system".

I installed git(2.23.0) from https://git-scm.com/

and

Visual Studio Code (1.39.2) from https://code.visualstudio.com/

When I start VSCode with administrator rights, git is correctly detected.

I've tried to add git path on Windows environment PATH + restart PC -> did not work.

I've tried to add git path on VSCode setting.json + restart like :

```
{
    // Is git enabled
    "git.enabled": true,

    // Path to the git executable
    "git.path": "C:\\path\\to\\git.exe"

    // other settings
}
```

--> that also did not work.

If I use "Show Git Output", the report shows me the correct path, but doesn't detect the git installation.

Comment: Is `git.exe` in the PATH or other options from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971624/visual-studio-code-cannot-detect-installed-git)?

Comment: When i finish to install VSCode and Git i didn't find git.exe path in envionment variable. So i try to add on user and system envionment variable "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe". That's not work. If I try to add path on VSCode setting that's not work too.

Comment: You can only add folders in the PATH, not an executable.

Comment: I also try to add folder "C:\Program Files\Git\cmd" but that's does not work

Comment: The folder that you add must contain `git.exe`.

Comment: i checked and the folder contain git.exe

Comment: When i start VSCode with administrator right, i get this report : Using git 2.23.0.windows.1 from C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe

Comment: but if I start whitout administrator i get this report on VSCODE : Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Users\paulp\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\cmd\git.exe
Looking for git in: C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe
Git installation not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution to solve my problem.
When I install VS code by default,is going on "C:\users[user]\AppData\vscode". 
and git default installation folder is "C:\Program Files\Git\"

When I try to call git function from vscode it come from my user directory and access to git is forbidden.

SOLUTION : I install git on my user directory and now it's work.